# How do you change the text or element while horizontally scrolling through a separate container?

Tags: javascript, parallax, jquery-waypoints, scrollmagic

I'm trying to change the text as you scroll horizontally through a container that is above the text. The triggers would be based on either pixels or percents, so for example--if you scroll to 20% of the image width, the text would change.

What is a good method to use for this?

I was trying to use waypoint initially, but it didn't seem to work because the offset feature isn't able to set according to percent or pixels when scrolling horizontally.

This is the setup--

```css
#overflow-scroll,
#overflow-scroll-offset {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: none;
}

#image-scroll {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background: pink;
  color: #fff;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="overflow-scroll" class="mt-3">
  <div id="image-scroll">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="blocks">
  <p class="block1">One text</p>
  <p class="block2 hide">Two text</p>
  <p class="block3 hide">Three text</p>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jlw01/seponjdh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding small jQuery script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#overflow-scroll").scroll(function(){
        var scrollRight = 200; //200 pixels
        if($("#overflow-scroll").scrollLeft() > scrollRight){
            //show block 2 and hide block1 text
            $(".block1").hide();
            $(".block2").show();
        }else{
            $(".block1").show();
          $(".block2").hide();
        }

    })
})
```

Hope this is what your were looking for.

Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dev_akash/seponjdh/2/)